# How to get cursor to focus on next empty field

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the First Name field was left blank, then the the cursor should move automatically
to the first name field after the error displays.

If the Last Name field was left blank, then the the cursor should move automatically
to the last name field after the error displays.

The cursor only stays on the first text box

```js
var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
$("#first_name").focus();

var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
$("#last_name").focus();

if (first_name == "") {
  $(first_error).text("You must Enter a First Name") return;
}
if (last_name == "") {
  $(last_error).text("You must Enter a Last Name") return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required>
<span class="error" id="first_error"></span>
<br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required>
<span class="error" id="last_error"></span>
```

Comment: Where are you checking "if left blank"? Your code is just reading the value of input field into a variable and setting focus on the field... one by one to all of them hence the last one will have focus. Please share the html code and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Focus only affects one control at a time, if multiple inputs are blank then only the last one is focused. You should be adding an error class and highlighting each invalid input instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields inside a parent div or form is empty it simply focus on that field
Use this function

```
function fieldsValidations(element) {
    var fields = $("#"+element).find("select, textarea, input");

    $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
        if (!field.value){
            $(field).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

and the *element* argument of the function is parent div or form's ID

Comment: As above, this code will focus on each element that is empty, but it will only focus the last invalid input. I would suggest adding an error class to highlight all the fields at the same time, making it far clearer to the user that a field is invalid.

Comment: @StuartFrankish https://jsfiddle.net/4pkzg30u/  return false in a `$.each()` terminates the loop.